# How to get content javascript in content html C#

Tags: javascript, c#, httpwebrequest

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var $grid = $('#file-list');

            $grid.jqGrid({
                height:     '100%',
                width:      '600',
                forceFit:   true,
                url:        '/downloadfolder/gridFile',
                datatype:   'json',
                colNames:   [
                    'id',
                    'Type',
                    'Name',
                    'Size',
                    'Link'
                ],
            });    
        });
    </script>
```

I create request use httpwebrequest and I get content html response
but content that I want to get in script tag
Somebody can I get this content

Comment: If you're trying to parse element contents from any HTML document (such as the text within a `<script>` element), then a DOM parser is generally the way to go.  Something like HTMLAgilityPack for example.

Comment: Please try to explain what you want to achieve. Do you want to download the csv grid file? Or do you want to execute the `javascript` part in `C#` on the server somehow? Whar is the target of your request? Which content do you mean?

Comment: @ventiseis : I want to get content in csv grid file